# Playwright component error: Cannot find module 'vite/package.json'

Tags: components, playwright

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run playwright component tests in github CI. Running it locally it works fine. Would greatly appreciate the help

Error: Cannot find module 'vite/package.json'
Require stack:

- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/plugins/vitePlugin.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/@playwright/experimental-ct-react/index.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/playwright-ct.config.ts
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/loader.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/runner.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/cli.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/cli/cli.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/playwright-core/cli.js
- /home/runner/work/project/project/node_modules/@playwright/test/cli.js

Comment: I encountered the same issue, and did an npm install vite. afterwards, the test runner was able to proceed. Were you able to get it working without installing vite?